# how to run job after build project in eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, software-design

I need to run a job/workspaceJob after building project. I already have a code but it is not consistent. I need to finish the building because I need the updated file in my process.Here's my code:`

```
 private void doSomething(final ModelResource selected) throws Exception{
    WorkspaceJob doSomethingJob= new WorkspaceJob("doSomething") {
      @Override
      public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        buildProject();
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
      }
    };
    doSomethingJob.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            doThis();
          }
        });
      }
    });
    doSomethingJob.schedule();
  }
```

`

I did the code above but no luck. I am expecting doThis() to execute after the job is done but it building always comes last.

Comment: This works correctly for me (replacing the method call with prints), the listener runs after the job is done. What does "buildProject" do - maybe it is doing something that runs asynchronously.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @greg-449 it does a FUll manual build on a project. 
My exact problem right now is How can I run a job after the Build job (autobuild from eclipse). 
I have a code that checks if there are unsaved editors, if yes then it will save all the editors open. (which will trigger the Eclipse's build job). 
How can I run my job after that? I have used the WorkspaceJob with overriding the runInWorkspace() but no luck :(

Comment: Builds run as separate jobs asynchronously. The job manager IJobManager lets you listen to events for all jobs, or you could try a resource change listener and look for the `POST_BUILD` event. You might also be able to schedule the Job immediately with a scheduling rule that prevents it running until some condition is satisfied.